# How to specify current directory for Azure Pipelines Docker task?

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, cd

I have the following task in my `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Building Docker image
    inputs:
      command: build
      dockerfile: 'mydir1/mydir2/Dockerfile.jvm'
      tags: |
        $(tag)
```

Unfortunately, `Dockerfile.jvm` is expecting it runs from `mydir1`. Can I `cd` to it before building?

Comment: Hi @Dims, Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0):

Your folder `mydir1` does not contain the file Dockerfile.jvm, right?  If it run the `Dockerfile.jvm` form mydir1, you will get the error message: `No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/mydir1/mydir2/Dockerfile.jvm  was found.`

You need to check your `Dockerfile.jvm` and notice the path and ensure the path is `mydir1/mydir2/xxx` instead of `mydir1/xxx`